# Ant design table force pagination

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying out Ant Design and been working lately on a CRUD app using the table component. The table datasource is linked to my component state, and when the datasource changes I was expecting to be taken to the first page, since my defaultCurrent prop on the table is 1 by default. But for some weird reason instead I get stuck on the same page as my last datasource. Any idea how I can make this work?

```
const TableContent = ({ tableData, title }) => {


const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState()


const columns = [
    'stuff'
]


return (
    <Fragment>

        <Table
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={tableData}
            rowKey={"_id"}
            style={{ padding: '0 50px' }}
            size="small"
            pagination={{
                defaultPageSize: 7, onChange: pageNum => {
                    setCurrentPage(pageNum)
                },
                current: currentPage
            }
            }
        />
    </Fragment>
)
```

}

Comment: `defaultCurrent` prop will only work when you don't pass the prop value. If you are passing any prop value to a component then default prop value will not be considered.

Comment: You can use a `currentPage` state that gets reset back to 1 after updating your data state. Pass this state as a `current` attribute into the `pagination` prop of the table component.

Comment: Hey @Scratch'N'Purr  I actually did that but then my pagination stops working. When my datasource changes I'm stuck in page 1

Comment: @SergioNeves what do you mean stuck in page 1? If you click a different page or next, it still shows that it's on page 1?

Comment: Hey @Scratch'N'Purr. When the dataset changes and the table renders again, I indeed go to page 1 using the current attribute, but if I try to click any of the other pages it doesn't work, I can't navigate

Comment: @SergioNeves What does your `onChange` handler look like? It should be observing for changes in your page and change the `dataSource` state when another page is clicked.

Comment: Hi @Scratch'N'Purr I edited my original post and deleted most of this component code for the sake of simplicity. My table datasource is coming from the parent component, and i'm trying to set the current page from inside the pagination prop using the onChange event. I also tried to set the current page inside useEffect but it also didn't work. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your table isn't re-rendering because `currentPage` is nested inside your pagination prop object. Even if the attribute changes, JavaScript won't detect it as a prop changing because the reference is still pointing to the same object. You'll have to deep copy the pagination object or add a `key` prop passing `currentPage` as the value.

Comment: Hi @Scratch'N'Purr my table is re-rendering just fine, but everytime it does I wanna get back to page one despite which page I was before

Comment: @SergioNeves could you possibly create a codesandbox with the minimal viable example, so that I can understand your problem fully? Earlier you said the pagination goes to 1 but gets stuck on 1, but now you say it doesn't go back to page 1.

Comment: Hey @Scratch'N'Purr, here you go I create a very basic example. On initial render you will get a table with fruits, please go to page 3 and then change to vegetables for example. You will see what I mean:  https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gauss-i04sx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SergioNeves Refer to my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-danilo-2z5gd?file=/src/components/TableContent.js) for the changes made to your example.

Comment: Thanks alot @Scratch'N'Purr it's working :)